# boost asio socket_select_interrupter throw exception connect time out

Tags: networking, boost, boost-asio

I have a client which use boost::asio to connect the server.But on some one's computer, When it try to connect,it throw the exception:socket_select_interrupter connect time out. What is the problem.I have find the source code,it is try to connect to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: post your code please.